# Hex pattern parsing in Python code (using Bitstring)

Tags: python, parsing, hex, bitstring

I'm prototyping a specific file editor and am having trouble parsing my hex files and finding a specific pattern. Here is my code (using the [Bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) library):

```
from bitstring import BitArray, BitStream, Bit
f = open('d:\BB.bin', "rb")
s = BitArray(f)
f1 = s.find('0x000015354444444343434344444444434343434444444400F700F0')

>>> print(f1)
(15232,)
```

This part is OK -- but I wonder what the output `15232` refers to? (In my file, the actual pattern is located at `770h`).

My main problem is looking for this kind of pattern but only with the 3 first bytes (`0x000015`) and the last ones (`0xf700f0`): I'm interested in getting the middle part only.

I've tried different solutions, but with no luck, any ideas?

```
f1 = s.find('0x000001''(.*)''F700F0')  
f1 = s.find('0x000001''0x.''0xF700F0')
```

Comment: Thx guys , you are mighty fast ;)

Comment: You should also use `bytealigned=True` in your call to `find`, otherwise it will look for your pattern at every bit offset, which doesn't seem to be what you want, and is also considerably slower.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you do not need bit-resolution and that `bytes` are sufficient.

```
import re
with open('d:\BB.bin', "rb") as f:
    f1 = re.findall( b'\x00\x00\x01(.*?)\xF7\x00\xF0', f.read() )

print f1
```

Comment: You're right, I don't need bit resolution, I will try with re module